# Which was the first abstract entity to appear in the Marvel Universe?

Tags: marvel, comics

Abstract entities or cosmic entities are physical representations of abstract things; I only know a few, such as Death and Eternity.

So - Which was the first abstract entity to make an appearance in the Marvel Universe?

Comment: Well there probably was a figure in a cloak with a sickle way back, because Death is a folklorish "antropomorphic personfication" (although the traditional one was usually considered male, unlike Marvel's). And so were the four horsemen of the Apocalypse. Perhaps it would be better to ask what was the first nontraditional abstract entity created specifically for the Marvel universe.

Comment: Retconned characters like [the Void](https://www.marvel.com/characters/void)? Presumably they're out..?

Comment: Can't believe [Q-Tip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Tip_(musician)) hasn't made it into a Marvel comic at some point. They could have used him [in this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/comicbooks/comments/c8tmce/spoilers_my_kingdom_for_a_giant_qtip_secret_warps/).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to the *[Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe A to Z #4](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe_A_to_Z_Vol_1_4)*, *[Eternity](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Eternity_(Earth-616))* first appeared in *[Strange Tales Vol. 1 #138](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Strange_Tales_Vol_1_138)* (**November, 1965**).

> ETERNITY: I am Eternity! Heed my message and remain silent! For none may speak when I am present!
>
> [image: Strange Tales Vol. 1 #138, page 16]
>
> <sub>*Strange Tales Vol. 1 #138* (November, 1965)</sub>

According to their entries in the *[Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe)*, the following entities all made their debut appearances after that:

- [The Living Tribunal](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Living_Tribunal_(Multiverse)) - First appearance: *[Strange Tales #157](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Strange_Tales_Vol_1_157)* (June, 1967)
- [Death](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Death_(Earth-616)) - First appearance: *[Captain Marvel Vol. 1 #26](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Captain_Marvel_Vol_1_26)* (May, 1973)
- [The In-Betweener](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/In-Betweener_(Earth-616)) - First appearance: *[Warlock Vol. 1 #9](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Warlock_Vol_1_9)* (October, 1975)
- [The Phoenix Force](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Phoenix_Force_(Earth-616)) - First appearance: *[X-Men Vol. 1 #101](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/X-Men_Vol_1_101)* (October, 1976)
- [Master Order](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Master_Order_(Earth-616)) - First appearance: *[Marvel Two-In-One Annual #2](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Two-In-One_Annual_Vol_1_2)* (December, 1977)
- [Lord Chaos](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Lord_Chaos_(Earth-616)) - First appearance: *Marvel Two-In-One Annual #2* (December, 1977)
- [Mistress Love](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Mistress_Love_(Earth-616)) - First appearance: *[Defenders Vol. 1 #107](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Defenders_Vol_1_107)* (May, 1982)
- [Oblivion](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Oblivion_(Earth-616)) - First appearance: *[Iceman Vol. 1 #3](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Iceman_Vol_1_3)* (April, 1985)
- [Infinity](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Infinity_(Earth-616)) - First appearance: *[Quasar #24](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Quasar_Vol_1_24)* (July, 1991)
- [Sire Hate](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Sire_Hate_(Earth-616)) - First appearance: *[Infinity Gauntlet Vol. 1 #3](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Infinity_Gauntlet_Vol_1_3)* (September, 1991)

---

Notably though, Death's first appearance -- as listed in the *[Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe A to Z #3](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe_A_to_Z_Vol_1_3)* -- is specified as her... (emphasis mine)

> FIRST **MODERN** APPEARANCE

The *OHOTMU* doesn't seem to list any of her prior appearances, but according to the [Marvel Database](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Database), her first ever appearance was in *[Marvel Mystery Comics #10](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Mystery_Comics_Vol_1_10)* (**August, 1940**).

> Two hands, like talons of steel, clamped down on Gudgeon's throat. His mind blurred and he saw, in the fog before him, the mocking face of death!
>
> [image: Marvel Mystery Comics #10, page 39]
>
> <sub>*Marvel Mystery Comics #10* (August, 1940)</sub>

Comment: Galactus and The Silver Surfer are at least semi-abstract. Cf. The Living Tribunal.

Comment: @Spencer - In _[Quasar Vol. 1 #37](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Quasar_Vol_1_37)_, page 11, Quasar states that Galactus is not an abstract entity, but rather, a physical being. Even if you ignore that reference, Galactus and the Silver Surfer didn't debut until _[Fantastic Four Vol. 1 #48](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Fantastic_Four_Vol_1_48)_ in 1966 anyway, after Eternity.

Comment: Very nicely detailed answer, but Nightmare preceded Eternity by more than two years.

Comment: @Klaus Æ. Mogensen - If we count Nightmare as an abstract entity, his first appearance precedes Eternity's by two years but succeeds Death's by 23 years. I'm not sure Marvel classifies him as an abstract entity though. Eternity and Death are both explicitly referred to as "abstract being[s]" within their _OHOTMU_ entries. Nightmare is not, and is instead referred to as a "demon."

Answer (score 11):

**NIGHTMARE (July 1963)**

The Lord of Dreams originally appeared in the very first Dr. Strange story in [*Strange Tales* #110](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Strange_Tales_Vol_1_110), July 1963.

Nightmare, an embodiment of terror-filled dreams, is the ruler of the Nightmare World, a realm within the Dream Dimension, which is a manifestation of the collective psyche of humanity, where people's dreams manifest a life of their own. He can drain psychic energies from the subconscious minds of dreaming beings.

[image]

Comment: I've been researching Nightmare to ascertain whether Marvel classifies him as an abstract entity or not, and while it's not wholly clear-cut, I currently lean towards him not being one. On the one hand, he did once refer to himself as a "conceptual entity" and he has been compared to Eternity in size and power. On the other, the _OHOTMU_ refers to him as a "Class Three demon" and makes a distinction between demons and abstract beings such as Death and Oblivion. Also, Nightmare appears to have a physical body, whereas abstract entities do not. I can provide citations for all of this at request.

Comment: @LogicDictates, do provide the link to above said information as it will help me to decide which answer to accept

Comment: @shanu - By citations, I meant that I could specify the issues I sourced my information from. Nightmare's entry in the _Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe: Horror 2005_ refers to him as a "Class Three Demon." The entry for Demons in _Marvel Zombies: The Book of Angels, Demons & Various Monstrosities_ states the following (on page 18): _"Abstract beings, such as Death and Oblivion, represent concepts and are not actual demons."_ That same entry also includes Nightmare in its list of specific demons (on page 21).

Comment: In _Quasar #37_, it's established that abstract entities don't have physical bodies and use Manifestation-Bodies (M-Bodies, for short) obtained from the Dimension of Manifestations when interacting with mortals. In the same issue, it's suggested that killing an abstract's M-Body will not kill the abstract themselves. In _Doctor Strange, Sorcerer Supreme #53_, Nightmare switches bodies with Dr. Strange, but then panics when Morbius the Living Vampire begins to drain his body of it's "immortal blood," stating that if his body is slain, he'll be trapped in Dr. Strange's body for all time.

Comment: Also note that my answer lists the first appearances of both Eternity (in 1965) and Death (in 1940). So, irrespective of whether Nightmare is a genuine abstract entity or not, he is definitely not the first to appear in a Marvel comic.

Comment: @LogicDictates, noted, I misinterpreted citation as sources/links, anyways since your answer gives a appearance predating this one, i'll accept it

Comment: @LogicDictates: It is worth noting that the 1940 version of Death wasn't part of the Marvel *Universe*, which is a much later thing; nor was this Death associated with any later Marvel Universe characters. And Nightmare does predate Eternity.

Comment: @Klaus Æ. Mogensen - I don't believe you've made a compelling case for Nightmare being a genuine 'abstract.' You've asserted that he is, but haven't cited a single Marvel publication where he was specifically described as such. In regard to the 1940 version of Death not being part of the Marvel Universe, the _OHOTMU_ does seem to hint at a divide between the 'modern' Marvel Universe and older stories, however it still acknowledges older stories as being canon. For example, it lists the first appearance of the original Human Torch (Jim Hammond) as _Marvel Comics #1_ (1939).

Comment: _Marvel Mystery Comics_ was a retitled continuation of _Marvel Comics#1_, and Hammond's entry in the 2008 edition of the _OHOTMU_ acknowledges a fight he had with Namor in _Marvel Mystery Comics #9_ (1940). It also lists Miss America and Namora's first appearances as having occurred in _Marvel Mystery Comics #49_ (1943) and _Marvel Mystery Comics #82_ (1947), respectively. Since Marvel apparently considers those other issues of _Marvel Mystery Comics_ to be canon, I don't see why Death's first appearance in #10 shouldn't be. Namor appeared in that issue too, albeit in a different story.